# Dynamic LINQ Query not working properly with Taxonomy field

Tags: c#, linq

I am using Dynamic Linq query. I am generating the query condition dynamically as string and pass to to the query. Below is the code I am using.

```
 var q = dc.ListDirectory.AsQueryable().Where(condition).OrderBy("Title");
 foreach (var p in q)
 {
   Console.WriteLine(p.Title);`enter code here`
 }
```

The above query workes fine (with other string fields even with large amount of data) except for the Taxonomy fields. As I was not able to compre the taxonomy field directly, i only took its string part to compare. Condition for Taxonomy field is like

Type.Label = "Text"

Quering with Taxonomy field condition:
With only 10 no. of items in the list it works fine.

But it fails when the no. of items in the list are around 419.

What i found is it starts executing foreach loop even before getting value in var q and give Object reference not set... error.

Any clue?

Comment: So where are you getting the `NullReferenceException`? On the LINQ statement? Or in the foreach loop?

Comment: In the foreach loop and only with Taxonomy field condition (when it has to go with 419 list items).

Comment: A few things that are unclear: [1] `Type.Label = "Text"` is not a comparison, but an assignment, typo? [2] `Where()` takes a `Func` of some sort... the code chunk mentioned in [1] is not one of those, so what are you actually passing? [3] If your code in the `foreach` loop is in fact what's in your program, and you're getting a `NullReferenceException`, there's really only one thing that can be null, `p`, so somehow you're LINQ statement is returning null items, but it's hard to give you any help without knowing what you're querying. If you provide more detail, please edit the question itself.

Comment: I have digged more into the issue and instaed of dynamic query I am using static query.  var q = from c in dc.ListDirectory where (c.[TaxnonomyColumnName].Label.Equals("Text")) select c.Title;
                    foreach (var p in q)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(p);
                            }    I tested with different "Text" values. For some it give 15 Title values out of 183 and then NullRefrenceException. For some its not giving any title. For some it gives 2 and the error. The same query is working fine in U2U.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for `c.TaxnonomyColumnName].Label.Equals("Text")` ... but that doesn't guarantee that `c.Title` won't be null (I'm not sure what `c` is in this case so I can't help you with why it'd be null).

If you don't want to get a null reference exception, then I you can add an additional where clause to filter those out.

```
var q = from c in dc.ListDirectory
        where (c.[TaxnonomyColumnName].Label.Equals("Text") && c.Title != null)
        select c.Title;

foreach (var p in q) { Console.WriteLine(p); }
```